# Closing UK Limited company

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, limited-liability-company

I'm researching my options for **closing my UK Limited company**. Over time my small business has acquired some minor assets such as computer hardware and an outside office building in my garden.

If I was to close the company, what happens to these assets? Would I need to pay tax on the assets, particularly the office building/shed?

Answer (score 1):

Many routes- simplest is to value all assets and buy them. Then pay a dividend with the proceeds. Take care to leave enough to pay all taxes etc.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there's something weird in the UK that I'm not aware of, the depreciated value of those assets is income for whoever acquires them, just like the balance of the company bank account is for whoever's account you transfer that into.